# Initrd - rebooting issue

Tags: initrd, system-recovery

I recently booted into Root via Ubuntu kernel recovery mode. When I finished what I was doing, and not altering anything in my system, I tried to reboot with `shutdown -r now`. This started various processes being shown terminating as indicated on the splash screen. But when the procedure reached a certain point it stuck with a message: *A stopjob is running for Save/Restore Sound CardState*. From that point it remained stuck, and the only thing I could do was to power down manually re my power button. I tried the same rebooting procedure again but it still stuck at the same point. However I later found that if I used `shutdown -h now` then my PC powered off normally, although that wasn't what I intended.

So is there any way while in recovery mode I can get past or skip a stage where the system gets stuck like this, without powering off my PC, and why is this problem occurring anyway?

Comment: How long did you wait? I thought stop jobs generally had some sort of timeout on them but I think it can be quite long (2minutes?).

Comment: @Philip Couling So did I, but in this case it seemed to continue indefinitely. In the end I gave it 10 minutes which I think is long enough.

Comment: I've never had this happen and don't have my Linux box to hand to test it out. Apparently you can enable a rescue shell on TTY9.  [See here under heading "systemd hangs on startup or shutdown"](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#systemd_hangs_on_startup_or_shutdown). Solution #4.  This might give you some chance to indentify exactly what is stuck.